# centos 7.4 can not install `dnf`from epel

Tags: centos7, yum, dnf

It is so weird, I have a centos7 VM box. Try to install `dnf` because it is a dependency of another package.

Most instructions on internet is like this:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install dnf
```

But nothing installs. `No package dnf available`

Even followed DNF blog: http://dnf.baseurl.org/2016/07/01/fresh-dnf-for-rhel-7-and-centos-7/

```
# cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/dnf-stack-el7.repo
[dnf-stack-el7]
name=Copr repo for dnf-stack-el7 owned by @rpm-software-management
baseurl=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/@rpm-software-management/dnf-stack-el7/epel-7-\$basearch/
skip_if_unavailable=True
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/@rpm-software-management/dnf-stack-el7/pubkey.gpg
enabled=1
enabled_metadata=1
```

Still nothing installs

```
# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

# yum search dnf
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net
 * epel: mirror.umd.edu
 * extras: centos.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net
 * remi-safe: remi.mirror.ate.info
 * updates: centos.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net
========================================================================= N/S matched: dnf ==========================================================================
dnf-langpacks.noarch : Langpacks plugin for dnf
dnf-langpacks-conf.noarch : Configuration file for DNF Langpacks plugin
etckeeper-dnf.noarch : DNF plugin for etckeeper support
python-dnf-langpacks.noarch : Langpacks plugin for dnf-2
mirrormanager2-mirrorlist.noarch : MirrorList serving mirrors to yum/dnf
```

#### How can I install dnf?  I assume this should be a trivial task.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: python3-dnf has been retired from EPEL 7 which breaks dnf. I'm digging into other solutions aside from epel. Will post an answer when I find a reasonable solution.

Comment: @MichaelHobbs I gather from your lack of posting, that there is no reasonable solution?

Answer (score 6):

WARNING: EPEL 7 DNF is very old and has issues to include security flaws. This appears to be the reason it was removed. That said here is the work around to get it working on Centos 7.

```
wget http://springdale.math.ias.edu/data/puias/unsupported/7/x86_64/dnf-conf-0.6.4-2.sdl7.noarch.rpm
wget http://springdale.math.ias.edu/data/puias/unsupported/7/x86_64//dnf-0.6.4-2.sdl7.noarch.rpm
wget http://springdale.math.ias.edu/data/puias/unsupported/7/x86_64/python-dnf-0.6.4-2.sdl7.noarch.rpm
yum install python-dnf-0.6.4-2.sdl7.noarch.rpm  dnf-0.6.4-2.sdl7.noarch.rpm dnf-conf-0.6.4-2.sdl7.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Okay, I give up.  DNF was quite a buzz last year but removed from centos epel silently.  I stop using anything that dependent on DNF.

Comment: When I have some time latter will update the answer to include how to build the newest version of dnf. While looking at a build option, the build instruction require you have dnf installed to build dnf. Really?

Comment: I get `Error: Package: python2-libcomps-0.1.8-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcomps(x86-64) = 0.1.8-3.el7
`

Answer (score 2):

This will install dnf-0.6.4 on CentOS/7.

```
curl -OL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tamama/repository/master/sh/tamama/node-provisioning/tamama-centos/7.3/setup.sh
sudo sh setup.sh
```

Comment: "curl this random shell script to your production server and run it as root"

Comment: be careful before you run this, looks suspicious, it does a curl to some random ip: `curl -L http://163.172.190.239:50080`